# Why does index.html, but not Index.html, change the size of my webpage?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
/* STYLE SHEET FOR INDEX.HTML */


/* Overarching Style */

html {
  display: flex;
  /* STYLE REST OF SHEET ACCORDING TO FLEXBOX */
  max-width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Hide horizontal scrollbar */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /* Add vertical scrollbar */
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 4vw;
  font-family: Garamond, Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif, Helvetica, Geneva, Arial;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background: url("Media/PexelsKyleRoxas.jpg") no-repeat fixed center center;
  background-size: cover;
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  /* Properties: flex-direction, flex-wrap, flex-flow, justify-content, align-items, align-content */
  /* Background must have this order: -color, -image, -repeat, -attachment ^scroll or fixed^, -position */
  /* background: linear-gradient(#EEF7FC, #47AAE8 50%, #EEF7FC); /* light blue */
}


/* Site Banner */

header {
  padding: 1vw;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100vw;
  color: #E9F1F6;
  /* light grey */
  background: url("Media/Banner.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  /* alternative: contain */
}

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: .5vw;
  font-family: "Brush Script MT", Didot, Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

.bannersubtitle {
  font-size: .8em;
}


/* Navigation bar */

nav.topnav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-bottom: 3vw;
  background-color: white;
  /* border-radius: 5px; */
  /* rounded corners */
}

nav.topnav a {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2vw 3vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 4vw;
}

nav.topnav a:not(.active) {
  color: grey;
}

nav.topnav a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

nav.topnav a.active {
  color: slateblue;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* Main Content */

.bigbox {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  /* Pushes footer to bottom, along with body, min-height: 100vh */
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 2vw;
  margin-left: 2vw;
  margin-right: 2vw;
}

.littlebox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border: .1vw solid slateblue;
  margin-bottom: 3vw;
  padding: 3vw;
  background: white;
}

.mainpost {
  color: black;
}

.previousposts {
  color: grey;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 1vw;
  margin-bottom: 1vw;
}

h3,
.pvpostsubtitle {
  color: grey;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 3vw;
  margin-top: 1vw;
  margin-bottom: 1vw;
}

p {
  line-height: 6vw;
  margin-top: 1vw;
  margin-bottom: 1vw;
}

a {
  color: blue;
}

div.divimg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

img.bodyimage {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2.5vw;
  /* width: 80vw; */
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 5vw;
  font-size: 4vw;
  margin-bottom: 2vw;
  color: white;
}


/* For devices 800px and larger: */

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  html {
    font-size: 3vw;
  }
  /* Main Content */
  .bigbox {
    padding: 0 2vw;
    max-width: 80vw;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}


/* For devices 1000px and larger: */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  html {
    font-size: 2vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <meta name="keywords" content="First, webpage, learning" />
  <meta name="description" content="My first webpage." />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Media/favicon_io/favicon.ico">
  <title>Chasing Freedom</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <h1>Chasing Freedom</br>
      <span class="bannersubtitle">and setting fires</span></h1>
  </header>

  <nav class="topnav">
    <a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a>
    <a href="index.html">About Us</a>
    <a href="Archives.html">Archives</a>
  </nav>

  <div class="bigbox">

    <div class="littlebox mainpost">

      <h2>About Us</h2>

      <p>
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
        sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.
      </p>

    </div>

  </div>

  <footer>
    Copyright &copy;2022. All Rights Reserved.
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

[index.html page shown as over 1200px, rather than expected ~800px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfALS.jpg)

[carbon copy of that same page, no window resizing, shown as desired ~800px; only difference is upper or lowercase "I" in html file link. Does this only when file name and link are both uppercase.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fe37.jpg)

I'm building a very simple, blog-style site from scratch. I've used "vw" for almost all size values, and every container is using flexbox.

Problem: Due to everything being sized off viewport, a difference in viewport size makes my page render very differently.
I have identical pages that dev tools says have differing viewport widths, despite no window resizing, and therefore due to my media query, are being rendered differently.

Troubleshooting: I've tried different combinations of renaming the affected index.html page and how it's typed/linked in the code:

- 1200px: doc name is *lowercase*, link in code is *lowercase*
- 1200px: doc name is *lowercase*, link in code is Uppercase
- 1200px: doc name is Uppercase, link in code is *lowercase*
- **800px:** doc name is Uppercase, link in code is Uppercase

The only difference in the code whatsoever is the doc name. So somehow the doc name itself is making the viewport wider...right? Is this normal, or am I doing something wrong, and will naming my file uppercase Index.html have consequences? (For instance, a hosting site requiring that the landing page be "index.html").

Relevant part of the above code:

```
<nav class="topnav">
    <a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a>
    <a href="index.html">About Us</a>
    <a href="Archives.html">Archives</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the html and css file?

Comment: @NipunaUpeksha I added a screenshot, does that work or do you need the whole file?

Comment: Please provide the code of the two files as well.

Comment: @NipunaUpeksha Alright they're added

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @NipunaUpeksha I'm just now noticing that in the first screenshot I've got (taken at time of original posting), the code in the preview between "element" and "body" doesn't match up to my actual code. I don't know what that stuff is. Does that have something to do with this? It's not showing up currently, though the inflated size is still there

Comment: `body` is for `<body>` tag. `element.style` is a part of your browser dev tools that indicates the inline style of the element which has a higher specificity value than other CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, the doc name does not have any impact on what you have typed inside the file. So you can either use `index.html` or `Index.html`. But it is good practice to use `index.html`.

And another good practice is to have all the `.html` files are in lowercase.
And I can see that the name of your `css` file is `index.css`. You should probably change it to something like `styles.css` which is another good practice.

Here, you are using `html: 2vw;` in media queries to change all the font sizes. But it won't happen since `<html></html>` is only a wrapper.
To do this you can either use `* : 2vw;` for selecting all the tags or change the font-size of the tags individually.

Comment: Thank you! Switching the `vw` value from beneath `html:` to `*:` solved the issue!! Dev tools still says the size between pages is different, which I don't understand, but all pages are rendering the same now, which works for me!